# If I have an SSD, do I need AMD Ramdisk?

Tags: windows-8, ramdisk

It seems like RAMDisk would cache a ton of stuff to my drive. With a standard HDD that's no problem, but for an SSD it raises the following risks:

- I have less space on my SSD
- Reading/writing to my SSD can kill it

I also already have 8GB RAM, which is plenty. Would RamDisk help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your specific usage case, but probably not that much.

First off, reading/writing to your SSD won't kill it in "reasonable" time, if its not a huge SSD and not doing server loads it will be obsolete long, long before it runs out of write cycles.

If you are using cache as swap, there is no point, you would be better off disabling swap - that way you don't have the overheads of swapping ram in and out (of ram!!)   In most modern OS's, "excess" ram is used as a cache which will reads from memory (won't help with writes, which are what supposedly eventually kill an SSD though).  Problem with using a RAM disk is that stuff goes "bye bye" if there is a power failure  - and you need to repopulate the RAM disk with files on boot anyway, so its probably not worthwhile doing in the general case - unless you have programs which write lots of temporary files which you can point to a ram disk.